# How to add drag and drop facility in a vaadin plugin

Tags: java, plugins, vaadin, orgchart

is it possible to add drag and drop option in an existing plugin in vaadin. Plugin is available in this link https://vaadin.com/directory/component/orgchart-add-on

Comment: I don't it's possible without modifying the addon

Comment: @AndréSchild [here's](https://github.com/FlowingCode/OrgChartAddon) the code. Why it's not possible using extension?

Comment: @Alex78191 Am using this plugin but i need to add drag and drop feature in it.. i.e,for example i need to pick a branch and drop it in under another branch.